# kafka-elasticsearch-consumer unit test issue

Tags: java, elasticsearch, apache-kafka

Hi StackOverflow community.

I'm working on unit tests for this project: https://github.com/Artemsetko/kafka-elasticsearch-consumer/tree/ES7
and faced with the issue. Basically, I was trying to test this method:
 [protected void postBulkToEs(BulkRequest bulkRequest)](https://github.com/Artemsetko/kafka-elasticsearch-consumer/blob/ES7/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/kafka/indexer/service/ElasticSearchBatchService.java#L86)

did smth like:

```
@Test
public void testPostBulkToES() throws InterruptedException, IndexerESRecoverableException, IndexerESNotRecoverableException, ExecutionException, IOException {

    String message = "test message";
    String eventUUID = "eventUUID";

    BulkRequest bulkRequest = new BulkRequest().add(new IndexRequest().id(eventUUID).type(testIndexType).source(message, XContentType.JSON).index(testIndexName));

    Mockito.when(elasticSearchClientService.getEsClient()).thenReturn(mockedRestHighLevelClient);
    Mockito.when(mockedRestHighLevelClient.bulk(bulkRequest, RequestOptions.DEFAULT)).thenReturn(mockedBulkResponse);
    Mockito.when(mockedBulkResponse.hasFailures()).thenReturn(false);
    Mockito.when(mockedBulkRequest.numberOfActions()).thenReturn(1);
    elasticSearchBatchService.postBulkToEs(mockedBulkRequest);

    Mockito.verify(elasticSearchClientService).getEsClient();

}
```

> org.elasticsearch.common.compress.NotXContentException: Compressor detection can only be called on some xcontent bytes or compressed xcontent bytes

```
at org.elasticsearch.common.compress.CompressorFactory.compressor(CompressorFactory.java:56)
at org.elasticsearch.common.xcontent.XContentHelper.createParser(XContentHelper.java:70)
at org.elasticsearch.client.RequestConverters.bulk(RequestConverters.java:223)
at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.internalPerformRequest(RestHighLevelClient.java:1758)
at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.performRequest(RestHighLevelClient.java:1732)
at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.performRequestAndParseEntity(RestHighLevelClient.java:1694)
at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.bulk(RestHighLevelClient.java:470)
at org.elasticsearch.kafka.indexer.service.ElasticSearchBatchService.postBulkToEs(ElasticSearchBatchService.java:96)
at org.elasticsearch.kafka.indexer.service.ElasticSearchBatchServiceTest.testPostBulkToES(ElasticSearchBatchServiceTest.java:143)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.mockito.internal.runners.JUnit45AndHigherRunnerImpl.run(JUnit45AndHigherRunnerImpl.java:37)
at org.mockito.runners.MockitoJUnitRunner.run(MockitoJUnitRunner.java:62)
```

Could anyone help me to make unit test properly. I need to validate whether call methods in the elasticservice, with the right parameters

Comment: Have you tried: `String[] messages = ['test message']` and finally  `BulkRequest bulkRequest = new BulkRequest().add(new IndexRequest().id(eventUUID).type(testIndexType).source(JSON.stringify(messages), XContentType.JSON).index(testIndexName));`

Comment: Yes, I have tried String messages = "{\"test\":\"testing\"}";

Comment: and  BulkRequest bulkRequest = new BulkRequest().add(new IndexRequest().id(eventUUID).type(testIndexType).source(messages, XContentType.JSON).index(testIndexName));

Comment: I've got
```
java.lang.NullPointerException
 at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.internalPerformRequest(RestHighLevelClient.java:1762)
 at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.performRequest(RestHighLevelClient.java:1732)
 at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.performRequestAndParseEntity(RestHighLevelClient.java:1694)
 at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.bulk(RestHighLevelClient.java:470)
 at org.elasticsearch.kafka.indexer.service.ElasticSearchBatchServiceTest.testPostBulkTo
```

Comment: I cannot mock       Mockito.when(mockedRestHighLevelClient.bulk(bulkRequest, RequestOptions.DEFAULT)).thenReturn(mockedBulkResponse);

Comment: @GiorgosMyrianthous is there any alternatives, because there is no JSON.stringify(messages), XContentType.JSON) in java 8

Comment: try with `{"message": "test message"}` or `{"test message"}` then